# Adding seconds to a Calendar object using Calendar.MINUTE add method

Tags: java, calendar, seconds, minute, java.util.calendar

Can we pass a long value in Java such that it adds only seconds in the following code:

```
Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.add(Calendar.MINUTE, (int) **SomeLongValue**);
```

Where **SomeLongValue** adds only seconds to the calendar object.

I cannot change the code. I have to pass a long value and increase `calendar` only by seconds.

Comment: Adding minutes will add `SomeLongValue * 60` seconds, by definition, yes... What's the issue?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Why do you want to do this? This sounds like [the XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: What is wrong with `calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND, 25)`?

Comment: @cricket_007 I cannot change the code. I have to pass a long value and increase calendar only by seconds

Comment: Okay, well, I don't think you can add a fraction of a minute

Comment: @cricket_007 yes thats right. Thats why I am here.. so is this impossible to do so?

Comment: As stated, you are adding seconds... Just in multiples of 60

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to achieve below:

```
Calendar calendar= Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.setTimeInMillis(calendar.getTimeInMillis() + (someLongValueInSec * 1000));
```

Comment: `calendar.add(Calendar.SECOND` should work fine, by the way

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to say no, you cannot add only seconds. You're adding minutes, and an integer must be a whole number. Therefore, the least amount of seconds you can add given that code is 60 seconds.

I would suggest using `Calendar.SECONDS` if that's the time unit you actually want to use

I also would suggest using a `LocalDateTime` rather than a `Calendar`. It has a `plusSeconds(long seconds)` method

Comment: If using `ZonedDateTime` or `LocalDateTime` from java.time (certainly recommended) you could obtain great flexibility by using the `add(Duration)` method. That would allow the client to pass `Duration.ofMinutes(240)`, `Duration.ofSeconds(45)` and all thinkable combinations of different time units. PS In the code in the question you can add 0 seconds and even -60 seconds and less; not that it helps the OP.